# Shifting the hue value of multiple objects in Inkscape

Tags: color, inkscape, tools

Is it possible to shift the Hue value of multiple selected objects by a certain amount in Inkscape 0.92?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Select your objects and apply Extension > Color > HSL Adjust.

Comment: Awesome ! , but why is "Live preview" feature so sluggish? Also Inkscape crashed multiple times . But eventually it enabled me to get the job done.Thanks :)